# How to automatically start VM created by virt-manager?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have created a virtual machine with virt-manager that runs on kvm/qemu.  The machine works well when started through virt-manager.  However, I would like to be able to start and stop the VM through a script in init.d, so that it comes up and down along with the host.  I need to have virt-manager show that the machine is running, and to be able to connect to its console through there.

When I use the command line that is produced by running `ps -eaf | grep kvm` after starting the vm through virt-manager, I get some console messages about redirected character devices, but the machine does start and runs properly.  However, I do not get any indication from virt-manager that it has started.  How can I modify the command line to get virt-manager to pick up the running VM?  Is there anything else about the command line that should change when starting outside of virt-manager?

Command line is (slightly reformatted for readability):

```
/usr/bin/kvm -S -M pc-0.12 -enable-kvm -m 512 -smp 1 -name BORON \
-uuid fa7e5fbd-7d8e-43c4-ebd9-1504a4383eb1 \
-chardev socket,id=monitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/BORON.monitor,server,nowait \
-monitor chardev:monitor -localtime -boot c \
-drive file=/dev/FS1/BORON,if=ide,index=0,boot=on,format=raw \
-net nic,macaddr=52:54:00:20:0b:fd,vlan=0,name=nic.0 \
-net tap,fd=41,vlan=0,name=tap.0 -chardev pty,id=serial0 -serial chardev:serial0 \
-parallel none -usb -usbdevice tablet -vnc 127.0.0.1:1 -k en-us -vga cirrus
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As far as automatically starting/stopping and you're using virsh you can do that like this (as a privileged user)

```
virsh autostart Domain
```

I'm not sure why virt manager isn't giving you any output. It does have a connection to the machine hosting machine right? It should show a list of domains if it's connected.

Answer (score 23):

Open the VM display, click View->Details

[image]

Select Boot Options, and tick Start virtual machine on host boot up

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The answer by Tim is the way to go, and
`virsh` allows you to do many useful things besides that.

To set a virtual machine to be automatically started, you use:

```
# virsh autostart <domain-id>
```

The `<domain-id>` is either the virtual machine's number, UUID or a "friendly name" like "debian1", which you entered in `virt-manager`.

To get a list of virtual machines (numbers and names), use:

```
# virsh list --all
```

In my case I get:

```
 Id Name                 State
----------------------------------
  1 other                running
  2 other-clone          running
```

So I've used:

```
# virsh autostart other
```

Answer (score 9):

install **virsh**
then

```
virsh list                    (this will print list of your VMs)
virsh dominfo your_vm_name    (get info about selected VM)
virsh autostart your_vm_name  (set autostart of selected VM)
```

Comment: if VM stuck at grub, virt-viewer your_vm_name, and boot up. After that, change /etc/default/grub, make sure that ``GRUB_TIMEOUT=0``. then ``update-grub``

Answer (score 6):

You can also place a symlink to the guest domxml in `/etc/libvirt/qemu/autostart`:

Will look like this for a VM named "test":
`test.xml -> /etc/libvirt/qemu/test.xml`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **KVM_AutoBoot** ( https://github.com/eduardolucioac/kvm_autoboot ) to start one or several virtual machines at server boot using KVM (libvirt). It is also possible to define an interval between the start of a virtual machine and the next one.

**Thanks! =D**