# How to automatically start virtual Networks using virsh?

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, virsh

[Following this answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/144460/how-to-automatically-start-vm-created-by-virt-manager), configuring domains to autostart using `virsh` is easy; set aside they fail with following error message:

```
error: Failed to start domain [name]
error: internal error Network 'default' is not active.
```

I can start this network manually by running `virsh net-start default` after restarting the host. How to also autostart the "default" network?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Autostarting networks is very easy and similar to autostarting domains: simply run `net-autostart` instead of `net-start`.

```
virsh net-autostart default
```